# Throwing error message when opening terminal

Tags: bash, bashrc

I'm new on Ubuntu and ROS. I installed two different distro. (groovy and hydro). When I open the terminal I take this error.

```
bash: /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

I remove ROS. I search on internet, type `gedit ~/bashrc` to delete `/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` in it.

But this file is empty in my case. How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, the file to edit is `$HOME/.bashrc`, not just `bashrc`, don't forget the dot (`.`) in front of `bashrc`. Open it from a terminal as:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and remove those lines.

Comment: This file is also empty..

Comment: Try to copy the version from /etc/skel: `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/`

Comment: There was an error as permission denied. I typed               'sudo nano .bashrc'
and deleted lines. Thank you..

Comment: You should own your .bashrc file and do not need to type sudo to edit it. May I suggest to change its ownership? Type: `sudo chown your_user_login .bashrc`